# not very good at css need fixes to match my old code

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this game for a while and decided to change my navbars to just buttons and I'm having trouble finishing up matching my style i had.

old code fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/L4hmpan1/38/

new code that i think is almost done : https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/yfcdqu5g/    ( can't get the last few things to work. not sure what the tab-container etc things need to say to make them work)

I basically want how my first fiddle looks on the 2nd one. its alot to post in here but i can post the css for both

old css:

```
body {
  margin: auto;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: arial;
}

.nav_bar {
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav_bar ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.nav_bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #6db1e4;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 23px 20px 22px 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  width: 75px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #96e0e9;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in;
}

.nav_bar ul li a#onlink {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.nav_bar ul li a#onlink:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

.main_container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  min-height: 400px;
  border-top: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.main_container p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

starting of the new css that i will use once done because it works with buttons:

```
body {
  margin: auto;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: arial;
}


/* remove border radius for the tab */


/* change border radius for the tab , apply corners on top*/

#exTab3 .nav-pills {
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}





#exTab3 .nav-pills>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #6db1e4;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 23px 20px 22px 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-radius-topright: 10px;
  width: 115px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}



#exTab3 .tab-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 860px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  min-height: 400px;
  border-top: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

I expect my 2nd fiddle to match my first fiddle in css style. i figured out that navbars = a list of links so what i did find to work should work . Active tab should be white and other non active tabs blue. But my actual output is close to my old style but not exactly. If i could get some help with fixing my css id really appreciate it. been wanting this fix for a few months now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below CSS to your code.

```css
#exTab3 .nav-pills>li.active>a,
#exTab3 .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover,
#exTab3 .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```